# How to get a second city in Bloons Monkey City?

Tags: bloons-monkey-city

The wiki description of the [Anti-Camo Dust](https://bloons.fandom.com/wiki/Anti-Camo_Dust) states:

> It is obtained by beating a random treasure chest tile **in your second city**.

How do I get the second city? I have an empty slot in my special items section - is that what I'm missing?

I cannot find anything anywhere, on Google, best answers are years old.

Answer (score -1):

If you search the wiki about the second city, it will tell you about https://bloons.fandom.com/wiki/Bloon_Dunes_(BMC). The second city is only available for the flash version of BMC.

Also, the second paragraph say this: "This Special Item is not available in the Mobile version, due to the absence of Bloon Dunes."